# Ajuda problema muito simples (C)

Tags: c

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Sou iniciante, alguém sabe me dizer se tem algo de errado? O software de correção automática só dá WRONG ANSWER, mas os casos de teste não quebraram aqui (C)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
float r = 0, areacinza = 0;

scanf("%f", &r);

areacinza = 1.25*3.141592*pow(r, 2);

printf("%.4f\n", areacinza);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uma das possibilidades, caso esteja usando uma plataforma de testes, como [URI Online Judge](https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/pt/categories) é que ele esteja usando um número muito grande e o float acabe estourando, poderia tentar substituir o `float` pelo `double`

Comment: Seu cálculo está incorreto. A área cinza se dá `Área do Círculo Maior - Área do Círculo menor = acma - acme`. Como o círculo maior tem duas vezes o raio do menor, basta `acma - acme = pi * (2 * r)^2 - pi * r ^ 2 = 3 * pi * r ^ 2 =` Área cinza.

Answer (score -1):

**O cálculo da área cinza está incorreto**

O correto seria:

`AreaCirculoMaior - AreaCirculoMenor`

O raio do círculo maior equivale a (3r)/2 e portanto a área do círculo maior é PI * ((3r)/2)² e a área do círculo menor é PI * r²

Assim o cálculo final fica:

'(PI * ((3r)/2)²) - (PI * r²)'

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Assumi o valor do raio do circulo cinza como 2 vezes o raio do circulo branco.

Isso não fica bem claro no enunciado.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define pi 3.141592


main()
{
    float raio = 0,
          result = 0;
    
    for (;;)
    {
        printf ("Digite o raio da circunferencia menor: \n");
        printf (">>>");
        scanf  ("%f", &raio);
        
        raio *= 2;

        result = pi * (raio * raio);
        
        raio /= 2;
        
        result -= pi * (raio * raio);
    
        printf ("Area da circunferencia maior: %.4f\n", result);
    }
    
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

***Peço desculpas por eventuais erros***

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).